# Unable to edit departure address

Tags: google-maps

On the website http://www.koenpackusa.com/Organization/contact we have a google maps map embedded on the page. Unfortunately I am unable to edit the departure address to calculate a route. Does anyone know why?

```
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m19!1m8!1m3!1d114966.4880391612!2d-80.356875!3d25.78038!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!4m8!3e0!4m0!4m5!1s0x88d9beb33ea21a51%3A0x78d9e8d9dc40bb18!2sKoenpack+USA%2C+1530+NW+98th+Ct+%23+104+%23104%2C+Doral%2C+FL+33172!3m2!1d25.7882014!2d-80.35730029999999!5e0!3m2!1snl!2snl!4v1437555682796" width="290" height="510" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>    </div>
```

Comment: I think you can only do that with the Javascript v3 api

Answer (score 0):

This isn't Embedded Map feature. If you look at Google [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#directions_mode), YOu can bot edit the origin or destination.